# Outlook email rule, Search table in body then move to folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I want to create an outlook rule were it checks the body of the email which has a table in it. It needs to check the top two cells of a 2 column table. As long as those match a specific text then move it to a folder.

For example here we have a table: that was in the body of the text.

| Name | Role |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Author |
| Linda | Reviewer |

Now I wanted to search for the email and find who the author was, is that possible with outlook rules?

I have looked around for the answer but this specific problem is difficult to search for. I have tried searching the body of the text for "Bob Author", "Bob    Author"(Tabulation) and even "Bob|Author" none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can create a rule based on the specific words in any message's Subject, Body, Title, Message Header and so on. There are no actions based on specific words in a table.